# How to change the url password_reset link in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a `users` app and I have links in urlpatterns but the problem is whenever I click on the `Forgot Password` link, instead of going to `password_reset` which I have set it leads me `userspassword_reset/` url. `userspassword_reset/` is a password reset page in admin page but I want it to be in custom page.

```
path('users', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.
as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html')
path('password_reset_done/', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done')
```

*Login Page*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="font-size: 50px">Log In</legend><br>
    {form|crispy}}
    </fieldset><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
    <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot your Password?</a>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
       Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
    </small>
</div></div>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: post your template from which you are calling forget password.

Comment: I have updated the code, Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first give name to url -

```
path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.
as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),name='custom_pass_reset')
```

then call it with name -

```
<a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'custom_pass_reset' %}">Forgot your Password?</a>
```